# TypeError: range expected at most 3 arguments, got 4

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
import openpyxl as excel


def bacaKontak(namafile):
    # Load File Excel 
    file = excel.load_workbook(namafile, data_only=True)


    # Load Data 
    setting = file['Setting']
    colNomor = setting['B2'].value
    colPesan = setting['B3'].value
    jedaKirim = setting['B4'].value
    jumlahKirim = setting['B5'].value


    print(jedaKirim)

    # Load Database
    database = file['Database']
    dataKontak = database[colNomor]
    dataPesan = database[colPesan]

    # Pengulangan
    for cell in range(1, jumlahKirim+1):
        kontak = dataKontak[cell].value

        print (kontak)

    targets = bacaKontak("./Sett.xlsx")
```

I got 2 errors :

1. File "C:\Users\Jtresst\Desktop\WAbot\kirimwa.py", line 32, in 
   targets = bacaKontak("./Sett.xlsx")
2. File "C:\Users\Jtresst\Desktop\WAbot\kirimwa.py", line 26, in bacaKontak
   for cell in range(1,jumlahKirim,1):
   TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

how to resolve them please? I use py ver 3.9

Comment: For starters, `replace range(1, jumlahKirim+1)` with range(1, jumlahKirim, 1). I am assuming you want a range between 1 and jumlahKirim with a step of 1. Try that first.

Comment: show full trace back

Comment: You declare a function, but never call it. That's not a [mcve], which would be expected in your question. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I don't see how `range(1, jumlahKirim+1)` can possibly cause the listed error.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JoshCrouse the complete error is "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" for range(1, jumlahKirim+1) .

Comment: Why your title states a completely different error?

Comment: Without knowing what the data is you're using. It's almost impossible to figure out your issue. However, the error leads me to believe it has to do with formatting. `'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` means you are trying to use a `float` in a way that only an `integer` can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to coerce to int, as `range` won't accept a `float`

```py
for value in range(1, int(some_input) + 1):
    ...
```

```py
>>> range(10.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>> range(int(10.0))
range(0, 10)
```